# mesosphere installation page reference /etc/defaults

Tags: dcos

Text at the bottom of https://open.mesosphere.com/downloads/mesos/#installation
says

> Mesos loads many configuration settings via environment variables,
>   which can be set in /etc/defaults/mesos, /etc/defaults/mesos-master
>   and /etc/defaults/mesos-slave.

I think the directory should be /etc/default  ( no s )

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for questions and answers. Unfortunately, there is no question in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github issue is probably a better means here :)

But if that is a question, yes it should be default and I will take a look into changing this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17043409)

Comment: If I try to interpret the following question "I think the directory should be /etc/default ( no s )", my answer says "yes it should'. Why would you say it is not a answer?

Comment: My bad - trying to report a bug and dcos listed this forum as a way to communicate. Everyone is right - it is not a question so much as a statement. Thanks!